# Is it possible to display a form instead of the challenge/response pop-up for an asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

We have an external SharePoint site that needs to be accessible to our intranet users and a select few users over the internet. The SharePoint site is on a separate domain from our intranet, but that separate domain trusts the intranet, so internal user's credentials work with the SharePoint site. As long as I have the trust settings in their browser, they will be automatically authenticated on the site.

The problem is external users. They also have accounts, but on our external network. By default they will receive a challenge/response pop up from the browser, and since they are not technically logged into the network they have to enter their credentials. I would like to be able to present them with a nice form instead of the challenge/response box. But I do not want to force internal users to have to type anything at all.

Is there a way to simply replace the pop up with a redirection to a form I can control? Everyone has to be authenticated, and in the end it is all windows authentication, I just want to control what people type into, but preserve single-sign on.

I know you can probably do this with multiple entry points into the application etc, but i was hoping to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is "Forms Authentication" in IIS.  It should work the same way that you described, but allows you to specify a page to redirect to.  I don't know the details, but you could try reading up on it here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, at least within the same web app. If you set IIS to allow both anon and auth, the internal users won't get their credentials passed in. If you secure the app itself using forms and deny, it will redirect both external and internal to the login page, but the internal folks won't have credentials for me to auto-login.